# Idempotent interface method in c#

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I am trying to create an interface that returns a modified copy of an instance that implements it and does not modify the original instance.

```
public interface ICensoreable<T> {
    T GetCensored();
}
```

And the object that implements

```
public class User:ICensoreable<User> {
    public User(User copyFrom) {
        this.name = copyFrom.name;
        this.password = copyFrom.password;
    }

    public string name;
    public string password;

    public User GetCensored() {
        User result = new User(this);
        result.password = null;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to enforce **on an interface** that GetCensored will not modify User (or T) instance?

Comment: No, C# doesn't support anything like this.

Comment: No, there's no way. At best you can document it shouldn't change the object. You can add the Pure attribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to the method, but this isn't enforced.

Comment: I've been ninja'd by two people, except that for Pure I was going to mention the ReSharper version. Still not enforced, but can raise a warning - and you are using ReSharper and have a coding standard that requires no warnings, right...? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#PureAttribute

Comment: You could define an interface that expresses your intent, but you can't enforce anything. Just like you can implement `IDisposable` but you can't force the class that implements it to actually dispose anything. This reminds me a little of `ICloneable`, but same thing there. Just because it expresses the intent to make a copy, that doesn't prevent the implementation from doing whatever it wants. (Thank you @BittermanAndy for introducing me to "ninja" as a verb.)

Comment: @JonSkeet "Anything" is not correct. He wants a Call-By-Value, this can be acchieved by using structs.

Comment: @kara: No, that won't guarantee that the method call won't change the state. For one thing, the struct can have a reference to a mutable reference type (e.g. a simple wrapper for a StringBuilder). You also can't guarantee that the interface implementation won't modify the value it's called on, even if that implementation is a struct.

Comment: I came across this question a bit late. Do you mind sharing the intention behind this interface please?

Comment: Don't you need `public interface ICensoreable<T> where T : ICensoreable<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the recent release of C# 8.0, you can now define default method implementations in your interface. Therefore, you will be able to enforce that **by default** the `GetCensored()` method does not modify the original instance. By marking the default implementation as `sealed`, the type that implements the interface is prohibited from explicitly reimplementing the method. Since the method is only implemented in the interface, you need to cast the object to `ICensoreable<T>` before calling the `GetCensored()` method.

This is the implementation that I used:

```cs
public interface ICensoreable<T>
{
    sealed ICensoreable<T> GetCensored()
    {
        var result = Clone();
        result.CensorInformation();
        return result;
    }

    ICensoreable<T> Clone();
    void CensorInformation();
}

public class User : ICensoreable<User>
{
    public User(User other)
    {
        name = other.name;
        password = other.password;
    }

    public string name;
    public string password;

    public void CensorInformation()
    {
        password = null;
    }

    public User Clone() => new User(this);
    ICensoreable<User> ICensoreable<User>.Clone() => Clone();
}
```

Using the `GetCensored()` method:

```cs
var user = new User();
var censored = ((ICensoreable<User>)user).GetCensored();
```

<strike>**NOTE:** As of the time of writing, this implementation **will** throw a `NullReferenceException` at the first line of the `GetCensored()` method (using C# 8.0 on VS 16.4.0 Preview 2.0). I personally assume this is a bug, since removing the `sealed` keyword will not cause any issues whatsoever with the exact same code. Furthermore, I tried another implementation which involved initializing a new object of type `T`, which also crashed. The line was `var result = new T();` and it threw a `NullReferenceException`.</strike> This is fixed in VS 16.5.4 onwards and the code runs correctly.

Theoretically, and as per the proposal, the `sealed` keyword simply prevents types from overriding the interface method and only keeping the default implementation.

**EDIT 1:** Currently at VS 16.4.0 Preview 5.0, the exception being thrown is `AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'`. After investigating a bit I realized that the bug has been known for a few weeks with a relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39692). In accordance with somebody this is fixed in 16.5.0 Preview 1.0 onwards, after a follow-up [fix](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/27756).

**EDIT 2:** Currently at VS 16.5.0 Preview 1.0, the exception is still the same; there was no fix for this issue being released yet.

**FINAL EDIT:** From VS 16.5.4 onwards (I hope), this code works just fine. No exception is being thrown.

Comment: You do need to constrain `T` to be a derivative of `ICensoreable<T>` in order to disallow methods that implement the interface and abuse it. `public interface ICensoreable<T> where T : ICensoreable<T>    {     }`